# G++-4.7.0 Internal Compiler Error Segmentation Fault with recursive type alias

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
using CallbackPtr = const std::shared_ptr<const T>;

template<typename C, typename T>
using CallbackFunPtr = void (C::*)(CallbackPtr<T>);

int main () {
    return 0;
}
```

results in:

```
7 : internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Compilation failed
```

Am I doing something outside of the C++ standard here and G++ doesn't have an error message yet?  Or is this a true compiler bug?

Comment: **All** ICEs are compiler bugs, by definition.

Comment: Just follow the instructions.

Comment: I have submitted it as a bug to the gcc bugzilla.  It is the first time I have ever seen an ICE so just wanted to be sure.  Will now know  what to do in the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine, it's a compiler bug. You might want to find the smallest test case and report it. On my copy of gcc-4.7.1, this

```
template<typename T> struct A{};
template<typename T> using B = const A<T>;
B<int> x;
```

is sufficient to give me an ICE. The culprit is the `const` here. Your example compiles when defining CallbackPtr as

```
using CallbackPtr =  std::shared_ptr<const T>;
```

Comment: I put it together and added a bug.  Thanks.  This is my first time submitting a G++ bug and I saw ICE a lot.  What does it stand for?